# How do garage door wire connectors work?

Tags: wire-terminals

This is going to sound stupid, but I have garage door wire connectors like this:

[image: garage door wire connectors]

The wire keeps falling out. How do I get it to hold. The manual and case says "Strip to this length: 11 mm and I've done that. Is there some other secret?

Comment: Don't you have to push that red leaver just next to the hole for the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a manual for a [similar opener](http://pdf.lowes.com/howtoguides/012381192779_how.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Do you recommend to use ferrules (for soft core wires) too for the quick-connect terminals?

Comment: Generally they're a "[cage clamp](https://www.wago.com/global/electrical-interconnections/connection-technology)" technology and work best with the flexibility of bare multi-strand wiring. See the link for Wago industrial type.